# Cumulative multidimensional array sum in R

Tags: arrays, r, apply

In R, how do you generalize the calculation of cumulative sum over different margins of a matrix to a multidimensional array?

For example, given the matrix

```
a2 <- array(1:6, dim = c(2,3))
```

> ```
>      [,1] [,2] [,3]
> [1,]    1    3    5
> [2,]    2    4    6
> ```

The cumulative sum over the different margins can be calculated using `apply`:

```
apply(a2, 2, cumsum)
```

> ```
>      [,1] [,2] [,3]
> [1,]    1    3    5
> [2,]    3    7   11
> ```

```
t(apply(a2, 1, cumsum))
```

> ```
>      [,1] [,2] [,3]
> [1,]    1    4    9
> [2,]    2    6   12
> ```

Note that some reshaping is required in the latter case. Now the question is:

How would you calculate cumulative sums for a multidimensional array?

E.g., for a three dimensional array like:

```
a3 <- array(1:24, dim = c(2,3,4))
```

I am interested in the cumulative sum over the rows, cols, and the third dimension, preserving the structure of the original array. Specifically, the row cumulative sum should be:

> ```
> , , 1
>
>      [,1] [,2] [,3]
> [1,]    1    4    9
> [2,]    2    6   12
>
> , , 2
>
>      [,1] [,2] [,3]
> [1,]    7   16   27
> [2,]    8   18   30
>
> , , 3
>
>      [,1] [,2] [,3]
> [1,]   13   28   45
> [2,]   14   30   48
>
> , , 4
>
>      [,1] [,2] [,3]
> [1,]   19   40   63
> [2,]   20   42   66
> ```

What would be the answer for an n-dimensional array?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Extrapolating from @G. Grothendieck's answer, this function uses `aperm` to calculate the cumulative sum over any margin of an n-dimensional array:

```
array_cumsum <- function(a, margin) {
  n <- length(dim(a))
  permorder <- append(x = 2:n, 1, margin - 1)
  aperm(apply(a, -margin, cumsum), permorder)
}
```

E.g., using a simple array full of ones for ease of eyeballing the cumulative sums, the function can be used to calculate the margin over the 2nd dimension:

```
a <- array(1, dim = c(2,3,4))
array_cumsum(a3, 2)
# , , 1
# 
# [,1] [,2] [,3]
# [1,]    1    2    3
# [2,]    1    2    3
# 
# , , 2
# 
# [,1] [,2] [,3]
# [1,]    1    2    3
# [2,]    1    2    3
# 
# , , 3
# 
# [,1] [,2] [,3]
# [1,]    1    2    3
# [2,]    1    2    3
# 
# , , 4
# 
# [,1] [,2] [,3]
# [1,]    1    2    3
# [2,]    1    2    3
```

as well as over the 3rd dimension:

```
array_cumsum(a3, 3)
# , , 1
# 
# [,1] [,2] [,3]
# [1,]    1    1    1
# [2,]    1    1    1
# 
# , , 2
# 
# [,1] [,2] [,3]
# [1,]    2    2    2
# [2,]    2    2    2
# 
# , , 3
# 
# [,1] [,2] [,3]
# [1,]    3    3    3
# [2,]    3    3    3
# 
# , , 4
# 
# [,1] [,2] [,3]
# [1,]    4    4    4
# [2,]    4    4    4
```

Answer (score 3):

One way is using a good old `for` loop

```
res <- a3
for (k in 1:dim(a3)[3]) res[, , k] <- t(apply(a3[, , k], 1, cumsum))
res
#, , 1
#
#     [,1] [,2] [,3]
#[1,]    1    4    9
#[2,]    2    6   12
#
#, , 2
#
#     [,1] [,2] [,3]
#[1,]    7   16   27
#[2,]    8   18   30
#
#, , 3
#
#     [,1] [,2] [,3]
#[1,]   13   28   45
#[2,]   14   30   48
#
#, , 4
#
#     [,1] [,2] [,3]
#[1,]   19   40   63
#[2,]   20   42   66
```

Comment: for n dimensions you'd need n-2 nested for loops, right?

Comment: @dzeltzer Provided you always want to calculate the row-`cumsum` of the 2d matrices from the first two dimensions then yes.

Answer (score 1):

This almost gives what you want but the result is transposed

```
apply(a3, c(1, 3), cumsum)

#, , 1

#     [,1] [,2]
#[1,]    1    2
#[2,]    4    6
#[3,]    9   12

#, , 2

#     [,1] [,2]
#[1,]    7    8
#[2,]   16   18
#[3,]   27   30

#, , 3

#     [,1] [,2]
#[1,]   13   14
#[2,]   28   30
#[3,]   45   48

#, , 4

#     [,1] [,2]
#[1,]   19   20
#[2,]   40   42
#[3,]   63   66
```

I don't know how can we transpose the result in the same `apply` call (there should be a way). I tried

```
t(apply(a3, c(1, 3), cumsum))
apply(a3, c(1, 3), function(x) t(cumsum(x)))
```

but this doesn't work. However, for now if we use `apply` again and transpose we can get the original structure back.

```
apply(apply(a3, c(1, 3), cumsum), c(1, 3), t)
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `apply` followed by `aperm`.  The only tricky part is getting the margins right:

```
aperm(apply(a3, -2, cumsum), c(2, 1, 3))
```

Each of these also work:

```
aperm(apply(a3, c(1, 3), cumsum), c(2, 1, 3))

aperm(apply(a3, c(3, 1), cumsum), c(3, 1, 2))

apply(apply(a3, -2, cumsum), -2, c)

apply(apply(a3, c(1, 3), cumsum), c(1, 3), c)

library(plyr)
aa <- aperm(aaply(a3, c(1, 3), cumsum), c(1, 3, 2))
dimnames(aa) <- NULL
```

Comment: `aperm` is the generalization of `t` I was looking for!